# Change app and keyboard language in Windows 10 answer file

Tags: windows-10, deployment, answerfile

I have an answer file for unattended Windows 10 (1809) installation. In the autounattend.xml I set the language preferences like this:

```
<InputLocale>041d:0000041d</InputLocale>
<SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
<UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
<UILanguageFallback>en-US</UILanguageFallback>
<UserLocale>sv-SE</UserLocale>
```

This will set the Windows display language to English and the keyboard to Swedish. The problem is that it will also set the "Preferred app language" to Swedish, which is not what I want. I want the apps to display in English, but only the keyboard to be in Swedish.

Unfortunately I did not find any documentation for the "app language" in the "[Windows System Image Manager Technical Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/wsim/windows-system-image-manager-technical-reference)" or the "[Unattended Windows Setup Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/)" or anywhere else after hours of googling.

So my question is; can I use an answer file to set the app language to English and the keyboard to Swedish?

[image]

Comment: All apps show as Swedish or just for specific apps? As my know, we can't specify apps' language to English through unattend file. But we could try to prepare an image in audit mode and switch app's language to English, then capture it again.

Comment: All Microsoft apps appear in Swedish